# Ajaxplorer FTP Passive Mode issues /IIS

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp, pydio

Im using Ajaxplorer as a ftp client to upload files. With small files works great, but there is a problem with bigger files (like 3G or more).
Apparently it does the upload fine, but when it finishes I receive a message that says the file is getting copied to the server,

> Copying file [my file] to ftp server

but a couple minutes later, it comes this

> ftp_fput(): Entering Passive Mode ([my IP address],9,132)

and ajaxplorer just stops the copying proccess.
Acording to the ajaxplorer log this is an error, but it doesnt say nothing useful

> INFO    guest   error   message=ftp_fput(): Entering Passive Mode ([my IP address],195,201)

my php.ini settings is the following

> post_max_size = 20G;
>
> upload_max_filesize = 20G;
>
> memory_limit = 100M
>
> max_input_time = -1
>
> max_execution_time = 0

BTW, Im using as a ftp server FileZilla version 0.9.41 and I getting this in the log

> (000256)24/09/2013 13:52:01 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.116)> Connected, sending welcome message...
>
> (000256)24/09/2013 13:52:01 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.116)> 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta
>
> (000256)24/09/2013 13:52:01 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.116)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
>
> (000256)24/09/2013 13:52:01 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.116)> 220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
>
> (000256)24/09/2013 13:52:01 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.116)> USER admin
>
> (000256)24/09/2013 13:52:01 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.116)> 331 Password required for admin
>
> (000256)24/09/2013 13:52:01 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.116)> PASS *********
>
> (000256)24/09/2013 13:52:01 - admin (192.168.1.116)> 230 Logged on
>
> (000256)24/09/2013 13:52:01 - admin (192.168.1.116)> PASV
>
> (000256)24/09/2013 13:52:01 - admin (192.168.1.116)> 227 Entering Passive Mode ([my IP address],196,30)
>
> (000256)24/09/2013 13:54:02 - admin (192.168.1.116)> 421 Connection timed out.
>
> (000256)24/09/2013 13:54:02 - admin (192.168.1.116)> disconnected.

Well... i think thats all i got, thanks in advance!!

---

-- [EDIT] --
Ok, I kinda solve it. 
I [installed and setted IIS7](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7) and later disabled my firewall. 
Now it uploads the files pretty fine, but after copying the same to the server it show some errors, like "It exceed the max time" or others, but if you refresh the page, the file is there.
Is normal to take so long to copy a file to the ftp server? (it takes a bit more than uploading) Im talking about big files here (2G or more), smaller files work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I finally solve it! :D

basically to upload big files in ajaxplorer you must to do this (for Windows 7):

- Set the following in php.ini

> post_max_size = 20G;
>
> upload_max_filesize = 20G;
>
> memory_limit = 100M
>
> max_input_time = -1
>
> max_execution_time = 0

- Install and set IIS7 [like this](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7)
- In [Your path to ajaxplorer]/plugins/access.ftp/class.ftpAccessDriver.php line 105 change @set_time_limit(240) to @set_time_limit(1000) or whatever you need (the numbers are the timeout in seconds)

Im not sure how it would work in other OS but maybe it would be useful to windows/ajaxplorer users :D